# conditional invoking of powershell script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell

I want a PowerShell script which will copy data from `table1` of `DB1` to `tableX` of `DB2` whenever there is a new entry (i.e. new row entry) in `table1` of `DB1`.

The script should run automatically so that this new row entry from `table1` of `DB1` should get copied to `tableX` of `DB2`

Is there is a way where to achieve this?

Comment: You would do this from the database using an `insert` trigger on `db1.table1`.

Comment: Look at `change data capture` and `change tracking` features too.